# OpenCV .xml file copying for object detection

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I'm new to Visual Studio, I want to run the OpenCV object detection code, [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) site says:

> Remember to copy the files haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml and
>   haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml in your current directory. They
>   are located in opencv/data/haarcascades

Can someone explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This means that when using/shipping you app, don't forget to make sure that these XML files are available and accessible.

Comment: Thank you for helping, currently the files are not accessible to my program, my question is how/where to copy them in order to be found by the program.

Comment: That depends on your installation process. One option is to put them with the executable. Another is to pass your app their paths.

Comment: Where should I put their paths?

Comment: Dude, you can hard code it into your app, or pass it just like any other param you pass to a program: args, config files etc. this has nothing to do with OpenCV. Just make sure the app knows where the file is when it is trying to access it.

Comment: As I said I'm new to VS, every time I try to start/build the code I get: 1>------ Build started: Project: openvc_program, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== So how should I link the file to the app (hard code it) - can you explain in details?

Comment: Seems like you added them to the build. That is not what is meant. They are needed for the app to *run* properly.